# How do I calculate the CDF of the chi-square distribution in excel?

Tags: excel, statistics

Does excell have a function for the cdf of the chi-square distribution?

If not then how do I calculate it manually?

I cant seem to find what I'm looking for when i try searching online.
This is the formula:
[image]

I simply don't understand how to plug values into the formula to calculate a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 2010 or later, there is a function for this.

`=CHISQ.DIST(x, degrees_freedom, cumulative)`

This function accepts three parameters:

- `x`, the value at which the chi-square distribution is to be calculated
- `degrees_freedom`, the number of degrees of freedom
- `cumulative`, a `TRUE` or `FALSE` conditional, false gives you the PDF and true gives you the CDF, so you'd want true

You can read more from [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/CHISQDIST-function-8b66784f-4e8d-480c-a8be-ddc1768341ec).

If you're using Excel 2007 or earlier, it will require more creativity as Excel's only built in chi-square distribution functions are for right-tailed probabilities.